# How to return an empty QString

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I made a function which returns a `QString`. At some points in my function, it should return an empty `QString`.

Just returning `""`, doesn't work. When I use [`QString::isEmpty()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#isEmpty), it's not.

My "emergency plan" was to return an "empty" string and check with it whether the text is "empty". But I don't think that's good style.

So how do I return an empty `QString`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The idiomatic way to create an empty QString is using its default constructor, i.e. `QString()`. `QString()` creates a string for which both `isEmpty()` and `isNull()` return `true`.

A QString created using the literal `""` is empty (`isEmpty()` returns `true`) but not null (`isNull()` returns `false`).

Both have a `size()`/`length()` of 0.

Answer (score 0):

According to the QString docs, returning "" should work; as should returning QString().

Try printing out the string you are testing to make sure it's really empty:

```
printf("xxx [%s]\n", myStr.toUtf8().constData());
```